# Text at beginning and right after a frame is indented in article-mode

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I use the Beamer-class + beamerarticle to generate from the same source a presentation and a script.
Whenever a Frame environment is displayed in the script, the first line at the beginning of the frame and the first one after the frame are indented.
Is there a possibility to execute a \noindent at the beginning of \begin{frame} and after \end{frame}?
Or any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution for my needs:
just put a `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in the preamble.